# Omnipay how to add new gateway

Tags: addition, payment-gateway, omnipay

Does anyone know how I could add a new payment gateway to Omnipay?

I read the blog https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/omnipay/j7OeQQSB95A

I followed the following steps:

1. Cloned the Omnipay repository using composer
2. Inside the vendor/Omnipay/ directory, added the new directory layout as per the stripe example

Now when am now trying to include my gateway, I see the following error:

```
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: Class '\Omnipay\Mygateway\Gateway' not found in 
C:\wamp\www\root\omnipay\vendor\omnipay\common\src\Omnipay\Common\GatewayFactory.php on line 79
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change anything inside the `vendor/` directory.

Just create a class `\Omnipay\MyGateway\Gateway` in your regular src/lib directory, and make sure it can be autoloaded by composer. Then you can use `Omnipay\Omnipay::create('MyGateway')` to create an instance of the class (or simply call `new \Omnipay\MyGateway\Gateway()`).

Comment: " make sure it can be autoloaded by composer." How can we map it with autoload of composer

Comment: Hey, can you please be more specific? I'm working on another gateway. 
Could you please write couple steps for creation? 
I added require to composer.json file and run composer update.