# Omnipay add new gateway

Tags: api, payment, gateway, omnipay

Based on this answer: [Omnipay how to add new gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216904/omnipay-how-to-add-new-gateway)

I try to add a new gateway for omnipay.

My folder structure:

```
lib/omnipay/newgw/
lib/omnipay/newgw/src/
lib/omnipay/newgw/src/Gateway.php
lib/omnipay/newgw/composer.json

vendor/omnipay/...
...
composer.json
```

In main composer.json I have:

```
{
    "require": {
        ...
        "omnipay/omnipay": "dev-master"
        ...
    },
    "autoload": {

        "psr-0": { 
            "": "lib/", 
            "Omnipay\\NewGw\\" : "lib/omnipay"
        }
    }
}
```

Do composer update.

In gateway.php:

```
namespace Omnipay\NewGw;

use Omnipay\Common;
use Omnipay\Common\AbstractGateway;
use Omnipay\NewGw\Message\PurchaseRequest;
use Omnipay\NewGw\Message\RefundRequest;


class Gateway extends AbstractGateway{

}
```

And when I try to run it:

```
use Omnipay\Omnipay;

class TestController extends ControllerBase{

 public function index(){
   $gateway = Omnipay::create('NewGw');
 }

}
```

It say's that class not found:

```
Omnipay\Common\Exception\RuntimeException: Class '\Omnipay\NewGw\Gateway' not found
```

I don't figure it out why the class isn't loaded. 
Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a new Gateway myself, I believe your problem is the fact that you are doing something like

```
   "psr-0": { 
            "": "lib/", 
            "Omnipay\\NewGw\\" : "lib/omnipay"
        }
```

And it should be

```
"Omnipay\\NewGw\\" : "lib/omnipay/src"
```

You are setting the namespace of the new library to lib/omnypay but it should actually be lib/omnypay/src

Comment: You can see my implementation here https://github.com/Mihai-P/tez-omnipay-eway . You should create a github and packagist package with your development so everybody can benefit from it.